# Example of an extension where Normal of a Normal extension is Normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

We know that in general Normal extension of a Normal extension may not be normal.
I want an example where it holds, i.e Normal extension of a Normal extension is still Normal. Is there any example of such extension ?

Thank you.

Comment: $\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb Q$.

Comment: This is a trivial one I think !..

Comment: By Galois theory every chain of finite abelian groups gives rise to a chain of finite normal extensions, where every "large" extension is also normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a non-trivial example: For $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ all the three extensions

1. $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$
2. $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$
3. $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$

   are Galois (and thus normal) extensions

Comment: Actually I am pretty new to the Galois extension, so will you please help to understand how the extensions are Galois ? @neptun

Comment: A Galois extension is a field extension that is both normal and separable, so I just quoted it as a well-known example. Proving it is a different matter altogether...  See here for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory#Example_1

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Actually, the compositum of two normal extensions of $k$ will be a normal extension of $k$. Everything else follows.

Comment: @Lubin, yes, but the asker asked for a concrete example!

Comment: And that’s why I gave you a +1